Dynamic Animation in Vue3
I'm looking for a way to do something like this in VueJS, without 3rd party libs or Js:


#progress {
  width: 200px;
  background: #E6E6E6;
  height: 16px;
  position: relative;

  &::after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0;
    width: 0;
    background: red;
    content: '';
    animation: forwards .3s ease-in progress-further;
    
    }
}    

@keyframes progress-further {
  to {
    width: 70%;
  }
}
<div id="progress"></div>



The 70% in the keyframe should be taken from the props, so the element is growing to the threshold we give it.
I tried using v-bind but the keyframes cannot be found when doing something like this.
I also had a look to Transition component but it doesn't seem to fit my need (I might be wrong)
Any thoughts ?
Edit: here's the code that does not work !
<script>
const props = defineProps({
  value: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    validator: (value: number) => value >= 0 && value <= 100
  }
})

const formatProgressAsCssPercentage = computed(() => `${props.value}%`)

</script>
<style>
@keyframes progress-forwards {
  to {
    width: v-bind(formatProgressAsCssPercentage);
  }
}
</style>


As the code you have given works, can you give us the code that doesn't work (i.e. what have you tried?)

updated my question, thks for notifying this out

Have you tried using a CSS properties ? Also It seems that a CSS transition would be a better match for what you are trying to achieve, since you could update the target value of the animation

I though about CSS properties tonight, i'm trying it today (transition are not really what i'm looking for, it does not need realtime progress, but i want it to fill until a certain amount when it gets mounted

As @GeogesA pointed out, it is smarter & more conveniant to declare it as a CSS var, and to use it inside the keyframes.
Something like this is actually working:
<script>
const props = defineProps({
  value: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    validator: (value: number) => value >= 0 && value <= 100
  }
})

const formatProgressAsCssPercentage = computed(() => `${props.value}%`)

</script>
<style>
.my-progress-bar {
  --my-progress: v-bind(formatProgressAsCssPercentage);

@keyframes progress-forwards {
  to {
    width: var(--my-progress);
  }
}
</style>

